# SQL query to find the most repeated 2 value across all columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have a table with all numeric values inserted in column 1, column 2, column 3.....
I know how to find the most repeated two values from one column but our goal is to find the most repeated two from all tables. Could you help provide any quicker thoughts?

Comment: Use `UNION` to get everything into one column, then use your known method to find the top 2 of those.

Comment: The fact that you need to do this suggests that your design is not properly normalized.

Comment: Rather `UNION ALL`, since you want to keep duplicates.